# Why does the following code crash on an iPhone 5 but not an iPhone 5S?

Tags: swift

```
func rand(max: Int?) -> Int {
    var index = Int(arc4random())
    return max? != nil ? (index % max!) : index
}
```

I get an exception on the last line: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that the iPhone 5S is 64 bit while the 5 is not, but I don't see anything in the function above that deals with 64 bits?

#### Edit

I was able to resolve the issue with the following adjustments, but I still cannot explain why.

```
func rand(max: Int?) -> Int {
    var index = arc4random()
    return max? != nil ? Int(index % UInt32(max!)) : Int(index)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me.. my app also crashed for same reason

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Int` integer type is a 32-bit integer on the iPhone 5 and a 64-bit integer on the 5S. Since `arc4random()` returns a `UInt32`, which has twice the positive range of an `Int` on the iPhone 5, your first version basically has a 50% chance of crashing on this line:

```
var index = Int(arc4random())
```

Your modified version waits to convert until you take the modulo sum with `max`, so it's safe to convert to `Int` there. You should check out [arc4random_uniform](http://nshipster.com/random/), which handles the modulo for you and avoids some bias inherent in your current implementation.

Answer (score 6):

As it seems like you found out, arc4random returns an unsigned 32 bit integer. So 0 to 4,294,967,295. Also, Int is a different size depending on the system that it is running on.

From ["Swift reference:"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_461)

> ```
> On a 32-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int32.
> On a 64-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int64.
> ```

On an iPhone 5, Int will only hold −2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647. On an iPhone 5S, Int can hold −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807. An unsigned 32 bit integer can overflow a Int32 but never a Int64.

[More information](http://nshipster.com/random/) on what random function to use and why.