# Swift Random Number crashes App

Tags: random, swift

I try to generate a random number in Swift and do diffrent statements with it, here is my code

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake{

        var randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random()) % 1
        println(randomNumber)

        if randomNumber == 1{
            println("ist1")
        }else{
            println("nicht")
        }

    }
}
```

If randomNumber == 1 becomes true the Application Crashed with

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCION (code_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Any idea what i m doing wrong?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC79Z.png

Comment: I just ran this w/ no problems.  Try cmd+shft+k to do a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Still does not work for me ... i added a few more lines (as i use this with a MotionShake)

Comment: This doesn't explain your crash, but `% 1` will always give you zero.

Comment: It actually might be related: beta version of the compiler might have problems with code optimisation. I believe this issue should be reported as a bug to Apple with crash reports, dsyms and a test project if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the following code crash on an iPhone 5 but not an iPhone 5S?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274265/why-does-the-following-code-crash-on-an-iphone-5-but-not-an-iphone-5s)

Comment: @A-Live true,.... i think its a bug