# Generate random alphanumeric string in Swift

Tags: string, swift

How can I generate a random alphanumeric string in Swift?

Answer (score 491, accepted):

**Swift 4.2 Update**

Swift 4.2 introduced major improvements in dealing with random values and elements. You can [read more about those improvements here](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-4-2-random-changes-wwdc-2018/). Here is the method reduced to a few lines:

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}
```

**Swift 3.0 Update**

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    let len = UInt32(letters.length)

    var randomString = ""

    for _ in 0 ..< length {
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
        var nextChar = letters.character(at: Int(rand))
        randomString += NSString(characters: &nextChar, length: 1) as String
    }

    return randomString
}
```

**Original answer:**

```
func randomStringWithLength (len : Int) -> NSString {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

    var randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: len)

    for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
        var length = UInt32 (letters.length)
        var rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
        randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
    }

    return randomString
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can modify the above to ensure that the generated alphanumeric string is 6 or 8 characters long only?

Comment: randomString(length:6) or randomString(length:8)

Comment: is this cryptographically secure?

Answer (score 64):

Here's a ready-to-use solution **in Swiftier syntax**. You can simply copy and paste it:

```
func randomAlphaNumericString(length: Int) -> String {
    let allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    let allowedCharsCount = UInt32(allowedChars.characters.count)
    var randomString = ""

    for _ in 0 ..< length {
        let randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(allowedCharsCount))
        let randomIndex = allowedChars.index(allowedChars.startIndex, offsetBy: randomNum)
        let newCharacter = allowedChars[randomIndex]
        randomString += String(newCharacter)
    }

    return randomString
}
```

---

If you prefer a **Framework** that also has some more handy features then feel free to checkout my project **[HandySwift](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandySwift)**. It also includes a beautiful **solution for random alphanumeric strings**:

```
String(randomWithLength: 8, allowedCharactersType: .alphaNumeric) // => "2TgM5sUG"
```

Answer (score 53):

You may use it also in the following way:

```
extension String {

    static func random(length: Int = 20) -> String {

        let base = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        var randomString: String = ""

        for _ in 0..<length {

            let randomValue = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(base.characters.count))
            randomString += "\(base[base.startIndex.advancedBy(Int(randomValue))])"
        }

        return randomString
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
let randomString = String.random()
```

Swift 3 Syntax:

```
extension String {

    static func random(length: Int = 20) -> String {
        let base = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        var randomString: String = ""

        for _ in 0..<length {
            let randomValue = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(base.characters.count))
            randomString += "\(base[base.index(base.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(randomValue))])"
        }
        return randomString
    }
}
```

Swift 4 Syntax:

```
extension String {

    static func random(length: Int = 20) -> String {
        let base = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        var randomString: String = ""

        for _ in 0..<length {
            let randomValue = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(base.count))
            randomString += "\(base[base.index(base.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(randomValue))])"
        }
        return randomString
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 2021

Comment: @RichardTopchii Can you clarify "2021"? Referring to a specific Swift version better communicates the incompatibility than a year.

Comment: It definitely doesn't work with Swift 5.9

Answer (score 40):

Swift:

```
let randomString = NSUUID().uuidString
```

Comment: UUID().uuidString now

Comment: UUID gives same string sometimes!

Comment: There are different kinds of UUIDs, some of them are time-based. [The one used in Swift Foundation is V4, random](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid). There is very little chance (like, [incredibly little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) that the same UUID will be generated twice.

Comment: Just a note that this doesn't generate a fully alpha-numeric string, as UUID's are restricted to the 0-9 A-F range of characters.

Answer (score 17):

**Simple and Fast** -- **UUID().uuidString**

> // Returns a string created from the UUID, such as "E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F"
>
> public var uuidString: String { get }
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid

**Swift 3.0**

```
let randomString = UUID().uuidString //0548CD07-7E2B-412B-AD69-5B2364644433
print(randomString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: ""))
//0548CD077E2B412BAD695B2364644433
```

**EDIT**

**Please don't confuse** with     `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString` it won't give random values.

Comment: Just a note that this doesn't generate a fully alpha-numeric string, as UUID's are restricted to the 0-9 A-F range of characters.

Answer (score 16):

### UPDATED 2019.

Here is an extremely clear function that **caches**. You should certainly cache as a matter of good practice. (There's also FWIW a tiny performance advantage to caching, which is of course totally irrelevant in an app.)

```
func randomNameString(length: Int = 7)->String{
    
    enum s {
        static let c = Array("abcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz12345789")
        static let k = UInt32(c.count)
    }
    
    var result = [Character](repeating: "-", count: length)
    
    for i in 0..<length {
        let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(s.k))
        result[i] = s.c[r]
    }
    
    return String(result)
}
```

This is for when you have a **fixed, known** character set.

Handy tip:

### Note that "abcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz12345789" avoids 'bad' characters

There is no 0, o, O, i, etc ...  the characters humans often confuse.

This is often done for booking codes and similar codes which human customers will use.

Comment: Upvoting for `repeating:count:`.

Comment: Measured performance in tests. This algorithm is damn slow. Only 5% faster than answers with letters.randomElement()!

Comment: @bodich it's inconceivable performance could matter, in any way, in the milieu under discussion. In an app, you might have to generate such a code (perhaps for login or similar) maybe "once" in the lifetime of the app. Note that if (for some unimaginable reason) you had to generate such a code *once a second*, then ... performance would still be an absolute non-issue.  It's a huge huge mistake to program for performance. You program for one thing only when making apps - reusability of the code, simplicity of the code, reliability of the code, cost of the code ..

Comment: In the incredibly unusual case that someone's doing some scientific programming or such, perhaps with server side swift, and for some unimaginable reason you need zillions of such strings per second in some sort of real time setting, then, the approach one takes wouldn't even be in the same general approach as the solutions mentioned here you know?

Comment: thanks for pointing out that I unclearly mentioned performance in the answer; edited!

Answer (score 14):

Swift 5.0

```
// Generating Random String
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}
// Calling to string
label.text = randomString(length: 3)
```

Comment: It's simply nice to have the controls over the String length. Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of several earlier answers for Swift 4.2. This is not new to Swift 5.

Answer (score 12):

With **Swift 4.2** your best bet is to create a string with the characters you want and then use [randomElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement) to pick each character:

```
let length = 32
let characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
let randomCharacters = (0..<length).map{_ in characters.randomElement()!}
let randomString = String(randomCharacters)
```

I detail more about these changes [here](http://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-4-2-random-changes-wwdc-2018/).

Comment: Instead of map you can use compactMap and then there is no need for ! operator. ;)

Comment: Hey @KristapsGrinbergs! My thought was that forced unwrapping would have better performance than using compactMap.

Answer (score 8):

A way that avoids typing out the entire set of characters:

```
func randomAlphanumericString(length: Int) -> String  {
    enum Statics {
        static let scalars = [UnicodeScalar("a").value...UnicodeScalar("z").value,
                              UnicodeScalar("A").value...UnicodeScalar("Z").value,
                              UnicodeScalar("0").value...UnicodeScalar("9").value].joined()

        static let characters = scalars.map { Character(UnicodeScalar($0)!) }
    }
    
    let result = (0..<length).map { _ in Statics.characters.randomElement()! }
    return String(result)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Loop free, though it is limited to 43 characters. If you need more, it can be modified. This approach has two advantages over solely using a UUID:

1. Greater Entropy by using lower case letters, as `UUID()` only generates upper case letters
2. A `UUID` is at most 36 characters long (including the 4 hyphens), but only 32 characters long without. Should you need something longer, or not want hyphens included, the use of the `base64EncodedString` handles this

Also, this function makes use of a `UInt` to avoid negative numbers.

```
 func generateRandom(size: UInt) -> String {
        let prefixSize = Int(min(size, 43))
        let uuidString = UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        return String(Data(uuidString.utf8)
            .base64EncodedString()
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
            .prefix(prefixSize))
    }
```

Calling it in a loop to check output:

```
for _ in 0...10 {
    print(generateRandom(size: 32))
}
```

Which produces:

```
Nzk3NjgzMTdBQ0FBNDFCNzk2MDRENzZF
MUI5RURDQzE1RTdCNDA3RDg2MTI4QkQx
M0I3MjJBRjVFRTYyNDFCNkI5OUM1RUVC
RDA1RDZGQ0IzQjI1NDdGREI3NDgxM0Mx
NjcyNUQyOThCNzhCNEVFQTk1RTQ3NTIy
MDkwRTQ0RjFENUFGNEFDOTgyQTUxODI0
RDU2OTNBOUJGMDE4NDhEODlCNEQ1NjZG
RjM2MTUxRjM4RkY3NDU2OUFDOTI0Nzkz
QzUwOTE1N0U1RDVENDE4OEE5NTM2Rjcy
Nzk4QkMxNUJEMjYwNDJDQjhBQkY5QkY5
ODhFNjU0MDVEMUI2NEI5QUIyNjNCNkVF
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 2.2 Version**

```
// based on https://gist.github.com/samuel-mellert/20b3c99dec168255a046
// which is based on https://gist.github.com/szhernovoy/276e69eb90a0de84dd90
// Updated to work on Swift 2.2

func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let charactersString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    let charactersArray : [Character] = Array(charactersString.characters)

    var string = ""
    for _ in 0..<length {
        string.append(charactersArray[Int(arc4random()) % charactersArray.count])
    }

    return string
}
```

Basically call this method that will generate a random string the length of the integer handed to the function. To change the possible characters just edit the charactersString string. Supports unicode characters too.

https://gist.github.com/gingofthesouth/54bea667b28a815b2fe33a4da986e327

Comment: For some unfortunate reason this version occasionally gives an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

Comment: Hey Joe, do you have any demo code that can reproduce this error?

Comment: Let me see what I can do; I was only calling it as-is in an IB action outlet with `let random = randomString(16)`.  The EXC was only on a real device and I didn't see it in a simulator and it was intermittent on the device.

Comment: See this SO question for the reason why this crashes half the time on 32-bit devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274265/why-does-the-following-code-crash-on-an-iphone-5-but-not-an-iphone-5s

Comment: **Important:** `random % count` does *not* (always) create a uniform distribution. If this is relevant to you, look to other answers that use `arc4random_uniform()`.

Answer (score 6):

A pure Swift random `String` from any `CharacterSet`.

Usage: `CharacterSet.alphanumerics.randomString(length: 100)`

```
extension CharacterSet {
    /// extracting characters
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133647/1033581
    public func characters() -> [Character] {
        return codePoints().compactMap { UnicodeScalar($0) }.map { Character($0) }
    }
    public func codePoints() -> [Int] {
        var result: [Int] = []
        var plane = 0
        for (i, w) in bitmapRepresentation.enumerated() {
            let k = i % 8193
            if k == 8192 {
                plane = Int(w) << 13
                continue
            }
            let base = (plane + k) << 3
            for j in 0 ..< 8 where w & 1 << j != 0 {
                result.append(base + j)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    /// building random string of desired length
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/42895178/1033581
    public func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let charArray = characters()
        let charArrayCount = UInt32(charArray.count)
        var randomString = ""
        for _ in 0 ..< length {
            randomString += String(charArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(charArrayCount))])
        }
        return randomString
    }
}
```

The `characters()` function is [my fastest known implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133647/1033581).

Answer (score 5):

**for Swift 3.0**

```
func randomString(_ length: Int) -> String {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    let len = UInt32(letters.length)

    var randomString = ""

    for _ in 0 ..< length {
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
        var nextChar = letters.character(at: Int(rand))
        randomString += NSString(characters: &nextChar, length: 1) as String
    }

    return randomString
}
```

Comment: Did you try that code? Did you notice that the returned string length is wrong, and that there are only digits? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/39566062/1187415, which has the same problem.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for pointing that out. i've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

My *even more Swift-ier* implementation of the question:

```
func randomAlphanumericString(length: Int) -> String {

    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".characters
    let lettersLength = UInt32(letters.count)

    let randomCharacters = (0..<length).map { i -> String in
        let offset = Int(arc4random_uniform(lettersLength))
        let c = letters[letters.startIndex.advancedBy(offset)]
        return String(c)
    }

    return randomCharacters.joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with responses to *"I need random strings"* questions (in whatever language) is practically every solution uses a flawed primary specification of *string length*. The questions themselves rarely reveal why the random strings are needed, but I would challenge you rarely need random strings of length, say 8. What you invariably need is some number of *unique strings*, for example, to use as identifiers for some purpose.

There are two leading ways to get *strictly unique* strings: deterministically (which is not random) and store/compare (which is onerous). What do we do? We give up the ghost. We go with *probabilistic uniqueness* instead. That is, we accept that there is some (however small) risk that our strings won't be unique. This is where understanding [*collision probability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem) and [*entropy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) are helpful.

So I'll rephrase the invariable need as needing some number of strings with a small risk of repeat. As a concrete example, let's say you want to generate a potential of 5 million IDs. You don't want to store and compare each new string, and you want them to be random, so you accept some risk of repeat. As example, let's say a risk of less than 1 in a trillion chance of repeat. So what length of string do you need?  Well, that question is underspecified as it depends on the characters used. But more importantly, it's misguided. What you need is a specification of the entropy of the strings, not their length. Entropy can be directly related to the probability of a repeat in some number of strings. String length can't.

And this is where a library like [EntropyString](https://github.com/EntropyString/EntropyString-Swift) can help. To generate random IDs that have less than 1 in a trillion chance of repeat in 5 million strings using `EntropyString`:

```
import EntropyString

let random = Random()
let bits = Entropy.bits(for: 5.0e6, risk: 1.0e12)
random.string(bits: bits)
```

> "Rrrj6pN4d6GBrFLH4"

`EntropyString` uses a character set with 32 characters by default. There are other predefined characters sets, and you can specify your own characters as well. For example, generating IDs with the same entropy as above but using hex characters:

```
import EntropyString

let random = Random(.charSet16)
let bits = Entropy.bits(for: 5.0e6, risk: 1.0e12)
random.string(bits: bits)
```

> "135fe71aec7a80c02dce5"

Note the difference in string length due to the difference in total number of characters in the character set used. The risk of repeat in the specified number of potential strings is the same. The string lengths are not. And best of all, the risk of repeat and the potential number of strings is explicit. No more guessing with string length.

Answer (score 3):

If your random string should be secure-random, use this:

```
import Foundation
import Security

// ...

private static func createAlphaNumericRandomString(length: Int) -> String? {
    // create random numbers from 0 to 63
    // use random numbers as index for accessing characters from the symbols string
    // this limit is chosen because it is close to the number of possible symbols A-Z, a-z, 0-9
    // so the error rate for invalid indices is low
    let randomNumberModulo: UInt8 = 64

    // indices greater than the length of the symbols string are invalid
    // invalid indices are skipped
    let symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

    var alphaNumericRandomString = ""

    let maximumIndex = symbols.count - 1

    while alphaNumericRandomString.count != length {
        let bytesCount = 1
        var randomByte: UInt8 = 0

        guard errSecSuccess == SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytesCount, &randomByte) else {
            return nil
        }

        let randomIndex = randomByte % randomNumberModulo

        // check if index exceeds symbols string length, then skip
        guard randomIndex <= maximumIndex else { continue }

        let symbolIndex = symbols.index(symbols.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(randomIndex))
        alphaNumericRandomString.append(symbols[symbolIndex])
    }

    return alphaNumericRandomString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    // whatever letters you want to possibly appear in the output (unicode handled properly by Swift)
    let letters = "abcABC012你好吗∆∌⌘"
    let n = UInt32(letters.characters.count)
    var out = ""
    for _ in 0..<length {
        let index = letters.startIndex.advancedBy(Int(arc4random_uniform(n)))
        out.append(letters[index])
    }
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 4**

Using **RandomNumberGenerator** for better performance as Apple recommendation

Usage: `String.random(20)`
Result: `CifkNZ9wy9jBOT0KJtV4`

```
extension String{
   static func random(length:Int)->String{
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        var randomString = ""

        while randomString.utf8.count < length{
            let randomLetter = letters.randomElement()
            randomString += randomLetter?.description ?? ""
        }
        return randomString
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `description`? Use `String(randomLetter!)`. You can safely force-unwrap `randomLetter` since it can only be nil if `letters` is the empty string (and that's obviously not the case here).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a unique identifier, `UUID().uuidString` may serve your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Swift 4. Use a lazy stored variable on the class extension. This only gets computed once.

```
extension String {

    static var chars: [Character] = {
        return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".map({$0})
    }()

    static func random(length: Int) -> String {
        var partial: [Character] = []

        for _ in 0..<length {
            let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(chars.count)))
            partial.append(chars[rand])
        }

        return String(partial)
    }
}

String.random(length: 10) //STQp9JQxoq
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.6**

This function generates a number which is 10 digits in base 36, then returns it as an alphanumeric string.

```
func randomCode(length: Int) -> String {
    let radix = 36 // = 10 digits + 26 letters
    let max = Int(pow(Double(radix), Double(length)))
    let number = Int.random(in: 0..<max)
    return String(number, radix: radix, uppercase: true)
}
```

Or if you never want the code to start with "0":

```
func randomCode(length: Int) -> String {
    let radix = 36 // = 10 digits + 26 letters
    let max = Int(pow(Double(radix), Double(length)))
    let min = max / 2
    let number = Int.random(in: min..<max)
    return String(number, radix: radix, uppercase: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.shuffeld(length:)` shuffles the alphabet. the returned String will not contain duplicates. if alphabet is shorter than length the returned String will have the length of alphabet.

`String.random(length:)` will return a String that may contain duplicates and is guaranteed  to be of size length.

```
extension String {
    static func shuffeld(length: Int, alphabet:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") -> String? {
        guard
            alphabet.count > 0
                && length > 0
        else { return nil }
        return alphabet.shuffled().prefix(length).map {String($0)}.joined()
    }
}

extension String {
    static func random(length: Int, alphabet:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") -> String? {
        let a = (0..<length).reduce("") { partialResult, _ in
            partialResult + alphabet
        }
        return shuffeld(length: length, alphabet: a)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
print(String.shuffeld(length: 15)!)
print(String.shuffeld(length: 3, alphabet: "abcdefg")!)

print(String.random(length: 100)!)
print(String.random(length: 10, alphabet: "☹️")!)
```

example output:

```
y37Ji8cLsPIQutr 
dcf 
UPfErOiryiuApH3HKHaZl6guY3LwXkmBqyyxqQAIw39lBK2R8mrwtbYKRhL80mZwkV2sf24No9PPXg6uwmUwVljbcUwSVeFBCUdD 
☹️☹️☹️☹️☹️
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `randomSample(count:)` from the Swift Algorithm package. Add it to your project via "File > Add package Dependencies..." in "Apple Swift Packages"

```
import Algorithms

extension String {
    static func shuffled(length:Int = 1024, alphabet:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") -> String {
        String(alphabet.randomSample(count: length))
    }
}
```

usage:

```
print(String.shuffled(length:6))
print(String.shuffled())
print(String.shuffled(length: 3, alphabet: "abcdefg"))
```

results:

```
FwHk5B
xNjKGiV3QhnPBFbZv5epUYC2zmgOD61kWR0qwsTcaHMt7lLAJu49XEyrd8ISfo
gdc
```

---

[Documentation for randomSample(count k: Int) -> [Element]](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/9dd88e5eafbd8dbdf3c2d1fd4b2016152fa0f0ac/Sources/Algorithms/RandomSample.swift#L151)

```
  /// Randomly selects the specified number of elements from this collection.
  ///
  /// This method is equivalent to calling `randomSample(k:using:)`, passing in
  /// the system's default random generator.
  ///
  /// - Parameter k: The number of elements to randomly select.
  /// - Returns: An array of `k` random elements. The returned elements may be
  ///   in any order. If `k` is greater than this collection's count, then this
  ///   method returns the full collection.
  ///
  /// - Complexity: O(*k*), where *k* is the number of elements to select, if
  ///   the collection conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`. Otherwise, O(*n*),
  ///   where *n* is the length of the collection.
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to define the character set and construct a string using random elements from that set.

Below is an example of a password generator using printable ASCII characters. For extensibility and efficiency, I've defined the character set as a static property on `String`. The function then takes an integer argument for password length and returns a random string.

```
extension String {
    static let printableASCII: Set<Character> = [
        " ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "\'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".",
        "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=",
        ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
        "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[",
        "\\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
        "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y",
        "z", "{", "|", "}", "~"
    ]
}

func getStrongPassword(ofLength count: Int) -> String {
    var password = String()
    for _ in 0..<count {
        password.append(String.printableASCII.randomElement()!)
    }
    return password
}

print(getStrongPassword(ofLength: 18)) // \g'CeTBRcLguQJ_(*S
```

*Note, that `printableASCII` contains 3 escaped characters in the Swift language, which are backslash, double quotation mark, and single quotation mark.*

Comment: Avoid vowels in autogenerated passwords. It cuts down on the risk of accidentally generating a password that could offend the user. Ask me how I know.

Comment: @HangarRash that is an interesting caveat! But then the password couldn't also be something inspiring and life changing, like `cupPycakEsprinkleS`.

Answer (score -2):

This is the **Swift**-est solution I could come up with. **Swift 3.0**

```
extension String {
    static func random(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let randomLength = UInt32(letters.characters.count)

        let randomString: String = (0 ..< length).reduce("") { accum, _ in
            let randomOffset = arc4random_uniform(randomLength)
            let randomIndex = letters.index(letters.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(randomOffset))
            return accum.appending(String(letters[randomIndex]))
        }
    
        return randomString
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
func randomUIDString(_ wlength: Int) -> String {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    var randomString = ""

    for _ in 0 ..< wlength {
        let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
        randomString = randomString.appendingFormat("%C", letters.character(at: Int(rand)));
    }

    return randomString
}
```