# How to generate random code mixed of numbers and letters - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to generate random code mixed of numbers (0-9) and letters(A-z) so I can send it to user email to use it when login .

Is there a library or any way to do this ?

Comment: For security reasons it highly recommended to use something hashed

Comment: Similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845307/generate-random-alphanumeric-string-in-swift

Comment: Very good answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512199/3177007

Answer (score 3):

This is give random value...

```
func returnUUIDWithTimeStamp() -> String {
  return UUID().uuidString + NSString(format: "%f", Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000).substring(with: NSRange(location: 8, length: 5))
}
```

**Result will contain '-'**

**C95B920A-3866-4A50-A783-D719FB0B607512830**