# App crashes when SwiftUI view with Picker disappears (since iOS 16)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

We have an application with some 'chat' functionality where questions are asked and the user can answer with some predefined options: for every question a new view is presented. One of those options is a view with a Picker, since iOS 16 this Picker causes the app to crash when the view with the Picker disappears with following error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` positioned at `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`. In the log I can see this error: `Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range`.

To troubleshoot this issue I refactored the code to a bare minimum where the picker isn't even used but still cause the error to occur. When I remove the Picker from this view it works again.

View where error occurs

```
struct PickerQuestion: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject() var questionVM: QuestionVM

    let question: Question
    
    var colors = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    @State private var selected = "A"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // When removing the Picker from this view the error does not occur anymore
            Picker("Please choose a value", selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.wheel) // with .menu style the crash does not occur

            Text("You selected: \(selected)")

            Button("Submit", action: {
                // In this function I provide an answer that is always valid so I do not
                // have to use the Picker it's value
                questionVM.answerQuestion(...)

                // In this function I submit the answer to the backend.
                // The backend will provide a new question which can be again a Picker
                // question or another type of question: in both cases the app crashes
                // when this view disappears. (the result of the backend is provided to
                // the view with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`)
                questionVM.submitAnswerForQuestionWith(questionId: question.id)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Parent view where the view above is used (Note: even with all the animation related lines removed the crash still occurs):

```
struct QuestionContainerView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject() var questionVM: QuestionVM
    
    @State var questionVisible = true
    @State var questionId = ""
    
    @State var animate: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeaderView(...)
            Spacer()
            if questionVM.currentQuestion != nil {
                ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    if questionVisible {
                        getViewForQuestion(question: questionVM.currentQuestion!)
                            .transition(.asymmetric(
                                insertion: .move(edge: self.questionVM.scrollDirection == .Next ? .trailing : .leading),
                                removal: .opacity
                            ))
                            .zIndex(0)
                            .onAppear {
                                self.animate.toggle()
                            }
                            .environmentObject(questionVM)
                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.questionVM.getQuestion()
        }
        .onReceive(self.questionVM.$currentQuestion) { q in
            if let question = q, question.id != self.questionId {
                self.questionVisible = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.questionVisible = true
                        self.questionId = question.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getViewForQuestion(question: Question) -> AnyView {
        switch question.questionType {
        case .Picker:
            return AnyView(TestPickerQuestion(question: question))
        case .Other:
            ...
        case ...
        }
    }
}
```

The app was made originally for iOS 13 but is still maintained: with every new version of iOS the app kept working as expected until now with iOS 16.

**Minimal reproducible code:** (put `TestView` in your `ContentView`)

```
struct MinimalQuestion {
    var id: String = randomString(length: 10)
    var text: String
    var type: QuestionType
    var answer: String? = nil
    
    enum QuestionType: String {
        case Picker = "PICKER"
        case Info = "INFO"
        case Boolean = "BOOLEAN"
    }
    
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26845710/7142073
    private static func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
    }
}

class QuestionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var questions: [MinimalQuestion] = []
    
    @Published var current: MinimalQuestion? = nil//MinimalQuestion(text: "Picker Question", type: .Picker)
    
    @Published var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection = .Next
    
    func getQuestion() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double.random(in: 0.1...0.2)) {
                var question: MinimalQuestion
                switch Int.random(in: 0...2) {
                case 1:
                    question = MinimalQuestion(text: "Info", type: .Info)
                case 2:
                    question = MinimalQuestion(text: "Boolean question", type: .Boolean)
                default:
                    question = MinimalQuestion(text: "Picker Question", type: .Picker)
                }
                self.questions.append(question)
                self.current = question
            }
        }
    }
    
    func answerQuestion(question: MinimalQuestion, answer: String) {
        if let index = self.questions.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == question.id }) {
            self.questions[index].answer = answer
            self.current = self.questions[index]
        }
    }
    
    func submitQuestion(questionId: MinimalQuestion) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double.random(in: 0.1...0.2)) {
                self.getQuestion()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func restart() {
        self.questions = []
        self.current = nil
        self.getQuestion()
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject var questionVM: QuestionViewModel = QuestionViewModel()

    @State var questionVisible = true
    @State var questionId = ""
    
    @State var animate: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("Questionaire")
            Spacer()
            if questionVM.current != nil {
                ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    if questionVisible {
                        getViewForQuestion(question: questionVM.current!).environmentObject(questionVM)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .transition(.asymmetric(
                                insertion: .move(edge: self.questionVM.scrollDirection == .Next ? .trailing : .leading),
                                removal: .opacity
                            ))
                            .zIndex(0)
                            .onAppear {
                                self.animate.toggle()
                            }
                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .onAppear {
            self.questionVM.getQuestion()
        }
        .onReceive(self.questionVM.$current) { q in
            print("NEW QUESTION OF TYPE \(q?.type)")
            if let question = q, question.id != self.questionId {
                self.questionVisible = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.questionVisible = true
                        self.questionId = question.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getViewForQuestion(question: MinimalQuestion) -> AnyView {
        switch question.type {
        case .Info:
            return AnyView(InfoQView(question: question))
        case .Picker:
            return AnyView(PickerQView(question: question))
        case .Boolean:
            return AnyView(BoolQView(question: question))
        }
    }
}

struct PickerQView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject() var questionVM: QuestionViewModel
    
    var colors = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
    @State private var selected: String? = nil

    let question: MinimalQuestion
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // When removing the Picker from this view the error does not occur anymore
            Picker("Please choose a value", selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.wheel)

            Text("You selected: \(selected ?? "")")

            Button("Submit", action: {
                questionVM.submitQuestion(questionId: question)
            })
        }.onChange(of: selected) { value in
            if let safeValue = value {
                questionVM.answerQuestion(question: question, answer: String(safeValue))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InfoQView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject() var questionVM: QuestionViewModel
    
    let question: MinimalQuestion
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(question.text)
            Button("OK", action: {
                questionVM.answerQuestion(question: question, answer: "OK")
                questionVM.submitQuestion(questionId: question)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct BoolQView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject() var questionVM: QuestionViewModel
    
    let question: MinimalQuestion
    
    @State var isToggled = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(question.text, isOn: self.$isToggled)
            Button("OK", action: {
                questionVM.answerQuestion(question: question, answer: "\(isToggled)")
                questionVM.submitQuestion(questionId: question)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `PickerQuestion`, `Picker`, try using this `Text($0).tag($0)`

Comment: I tried to add the tag but it doesn't prevent the crash

Comment: on what line does the error occurs?

Comment: It does not occur in one of my views, xcode jumps to `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` directly with the message `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`. In the log I see this error `Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: show us a minimal reproducible code that produces your error,  a `Minimal Reproducible Example`: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @workingdogsupportUkraine, I've added a Minimal Reproducible Example in my original question. (Add `TestView` in your `ContentView`). Iterate over the questions (generated randomly). at some point it will crash when the Picker is used. (Note: also here it just fails on iOS 16)

Comment: I had a quick look at your example code, and can reproduce the crash. I'm still baffled.

Comment: Have you find solution ?
I'm face same issue on last update, when I change it to `.pickerStyle(.menu)`
the crash won't happened, it the issue only with .wheel

Comment: Hi @Basel, I haven't found a solution yet: we've made some design changes to avoid the picker for now until a solution is found

Comment: @Vama try my solution, it working fine without any crash !

Comment: @Basel, it's been a while since I've had the time to check on this issue. I've accepted Araxias answer since it's a solution in SwiftUI without using UIKit. I will try your answer later to see if it also works for our issue.

Comment: @Basel, tested your solution: it works as well but I left Araxias answer marked as solution since I can not accept multiple answers and Araxias answer is in pure SwiftUI without UIKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This crash still exists on iOS 16.2. It seems to only occur when you use `ForEach` within your `Picker` view. Thus the crash disappears when you manually provide each picker option's `Text` view in the `Picker` content instead of using `ForEach` to create the `Text` picker options.

Of course, hard-coding the picker options is not a feasible workaround in many cases.

But you can also work around the problem by moving the `ForEach`-loop that generates the picker options into another view. To achieve this define a helper view:

```
struct PickerContent<Data>: View where Data : RandomAccessCollection, Data.Element : Hashable {
    let pickerValues: Data
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(pickerValues, id: \.self) {
            let text = "\($0)"
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `PickerContent` in your `Picker` instead of `ForEach`, e.g. (based on your example):

```
Picker("Please choose a value", selection: $selected) {
    PickerContent(pickerValues: colors)
}.pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

Comment: This works indeed for the issue we were experiencing!

Comment: Thank you. This is a very unusual issue that I did not find in any documentation. This solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in iOS 16.x while using Picker with "wheel style", I had the same issue in my app and used the following workaround:

```
extension Picker {
    @ViewBuilder
    func pickerViewModifier() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            self
        } else {
            self.pickerStyle(.wheel)
        }
    }
 }

 struct SomeView: View {
     var body: some View {
         Picker()
             .pickerViewModifier()
     }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seems a workaround. What it simply does is sets the `.default` picker style instead of `.wheel` pickerstyle in iOS 16.0.

Comment: It's a workaround for the crash itself, there is no other solution to avoid the crash on iOS 16, at least I didn't find any solution yet to avoid it. @WhiteSpidy please let me know if you find any other solution.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041284) for a workaround to avoid the crash on iOS 16 while still using the `.wheel` picker style.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find a solution using SwiftUI Picker

but I found a solution using the UIKit version

I faced the same issue in my app, after using the UIKit version, the Pickerview wheel style worked fine without any crash

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var array: [String]
    @Binding var selectedItem: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIPickerView {
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPickerView, context: Context) {
        uiView.selectRow(array.firstIndex(of: selectedItem) ?? 0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
        var parent: PickerView

        init(_ picker: PickerView) {
            self.parent = picker
        }

        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            1
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            parent.array.count
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            parent.array[row]
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            parent.selectedItem = parent.array[row]
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
   PickerView(array: myArray, selectedItem: $mySelectedItem)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the same issue with iOS 16.0 and to get the exact same solution nothing worked and at last I had to used UIKit's wrapper with `PickerView()` in it. Also it only happens with `wheel` style I guess `default` works fine for me.
Here's the working code to get the same exact `wheel` picker in iOS 16.

```
struct CustomUIPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var items: [String]
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomPickerCoordinator {
        CustomPickerCoordinator(items: $items, selectedIndex: $selectedIndex)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIPickerView {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = context.coordinator
        pickerView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pickerView.selectRow(selectedIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        return pickerView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPickerView, context: Context) {
    }
}

extension CustomUIPicker {
    
    class CustomPickerCoordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
        
        @Binding private var items: [String]
        @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
        
        init(items: Binding<[String]>, selectedIndex: Binding<Int>) {
            _items = items
            _selectedIndex = selectedIndex
        }
        
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            1
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            items.count
        }
        
        func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return items[row]
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            selectedIndex = row
        }
    }
}
```

Here `items` is list of data you want to display in your `wheel` picker and `selectedIndex` is current selected index of your `picker view`.

Comment: Binding should only be used in a SwiftUI view not a class