# What type to use for timeIntervalSince1970 in ms?

Tags: swift, swift2

I need time since Epoch in ms for an API request, so I'm looking to have a function that converts my `myUIDatePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970` into milliseconds by multiplying by 1000. My question is what should the return value be?

Right now I have

```
func setTimeSinceEpoch(datePicker: UIDatePicker) -> Int {
    return Int(datePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
}
```

Will this cause any issues? I need an integer, not a floating point, but will I have issues with overflow? I tested it out with print statements and it seems to work but I want to find the best way of doing this.

Comment: no idea in swift, but in cocoa land there is something called `NSTimeInterval`

Comment: NSTimeInterval is actually a Double, so you could use a Double

Comment: It's what comes after the decimal you're interested in for milliseconds. You might find some more insight here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c

Comment: Assuming that's IEEE 64-bit double-precision floating-point, it can store the current time since 1970 with a precision of about 244 nanoseconds.

Comment: @GradyPlayer `NSTimeInterval` is available in Swift: `public typealias NSTimeInterval = Double`

Comment: @Tommy, Mark tour question as solved if so.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSTimeIntervalSince1970):

```
var NSTimeIntervalSince1970: Double { get }
```

There is a nice function called distantFuture. Even if you use this date in you func the result will be smaller then the max Int.

```
let future = NSDate.distantFuture() // "Jan 1, 4001, 12:00 AM"
print((Int(future.timeIntervalSince1970) * 1000) < Int.max) // true
```

So, until 4001 you're good to go. It will work perfectly on 64-bits systems.

Note: If your system supports iPhone 5 (32-bits) it's going to get an error on pretty much any date you use. Int in Iphone 5 corresponds to Int32. 
Returning an Int64 is a better approach. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274265/why-does-the-following-code-crash-on-an-iphone-5-but-not-an-iphone-5s).